# Interceptor is not get invoked if get beans created in servlet-context in spring-config. in Spring Framework

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, component-scan, servletconfig

I added code  in servlet context instead of spring-web.xml, that time interceptor not got invoked, but when I added  in spring-web.xml it invoked.. Not getting reason. Is any one can tell the reason.

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-beans.xml</param-value>
```

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**spring-beans.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.*" />
```

**spring-web.xml**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*.do"/>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*.srvc"/>
        <bean class="com.abc.web.interceptor.ControllerSessionCheckInterceptor" parent="excludeIncludeControllerInterceptorActions" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>  
<bean id="excludeIncludeControllerInterceptorActions" abstract="true">
    <property name="excludeURLList">
        <list>
            <value>/account/signIn.do</value>
            <value>/account/authenticate.srvc</value>
            <value>/account/authenticateMobile.srvc</value>
            <value>/account/checkImei.do</value>
            <value>/account/signOut.do</value>
            <value>/account/signInBack.do</value>
            <value>/account/forgotUserPassword.do</value>               
            <value>/error/sessionExpired.do</value>
            <value>/account/loadResetPassword.do</value>
            <value>/error/errorHandler.do</value>
            <value>/error/404.do</value>
            <value>/error/500.do</value>
            <value>/error/pageNotFound.do</value>
            <value>/error/serverError.do</value>
            <value>/account/getPublicKey.srvc</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
<!--    This actions are used when there is no ajax calls.  -->
     <property name="redirectUrlList">
        <list>
            <value>/account/homePage.do</value>
            <value>/emailController/sendEMailWithAttachment.do</value>
            <value>/document/downloadDocument.do</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is any one having this problems description?? why its like this behaviour.